# How to Add a unique value in RDD spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I am using scala to identify a 1st word of the row and create a unique value and append it in the RDD. But i don't know how to do that. I am new to scala so please forgive if this question sounds lame.
Sample that i am trying is given below.

**Sample:**

```
OBR|1|METABOLIC PANEL
OBX|1|Glucose
OBX|2|BUN
OBX|3|CREATININE
OBR|2|RFLX TO VERIFICATION
OBX|1|EGFR
OBX|2|SODIUM
OBR|3|AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT
OBX|1|POTASSIUM
```

I want to check if the first word is **OBR** or not if it is OBR than i create a unique value and want to append it in the OBR and underneath **OBX** untill i found one more OBR this i want to do. But how can i do this ? I am bringing my data from **HDFS**.

**Expected Result :**

```
OBR|1|METABOLIC PANEL|OBR_filename_1
OBX|1|Glucose|OBR_filename_1
OBX|2|BUN|OBR_filename_1
OBX|3|CREATININE|OBR_filename_1
OBR|2|RFLX TO VERIFICATION|OBR_filename_2
OBX|1|EGFR|OBR_filename_2
OBX|2|SODIUM|OBR_filename_2
OBR|3|AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT|OBR_filename_3
OBX|1|POTASSIUM|OBR_filename_3
```

Comment: In a distributed system such as spark and hdfs there is no such thing as reading a file in order. How would you like the code to behave for example if all the OBRs are read in first, then all the others after that? Would you like all the other records to get the last filename? If not however if you're running your application with a single core on a single file then you'll prbably get the file read in in the order you expected but at that point why use spark?

Comment: @ASpotySpot i want to read it sequentially and check if it gets **OBR** as first value than create `OBR_filename_id` and put the same `OBR_filename_id` in all obx until it reaches next **OBR**

Comment: So your file is split into many parts since it is on hdfs. What does it mean to be read sequentially for example? If it is not split into many parts then getting spark to operate on it sequentially anyway is tricky (as far as I know) since regardless of how you do it it will process parts of the file in parallel unless you use a single core. I could put something together but at that point its pointless using spark I believe.

Comment: in my HDFS this file is a single core, it is not splited in parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so as mentioned in my comment this will only work on a single core and shouldn't be done using spark unless someone can shed some light on something I'm missing.
I'm assuming the file is just a text file on hdfs as described in your example.

```
val text: RDD[(String, Long)] = sc.textFile(<path>).zipWithIndex
val tupled: RDD[((String, Int, String), Int)] = text.map{case (r, i) => (r.split('|'), i)).map{case (s, i) => ((s(0), s(1).toInt, s(2)), i)}
val obrToFirstIndex: Array[(Int, Long)] = tupled.filter(_._1._1 == "OBR").map{case (t, i) => (t._2, i)}.reduceByKey(Math.min).collect()
val bcIndexes = sc.broadcast(obrToFirstIndex.sortBy(_._2))
val withObr = tupled.mapValues(i => bcIndexes.value.find(_._2 >= i).getOrElse(bcIndexes.value.last)._1)
val result: RDD[String] = withObr.map{case ((t1, t2, t2), obrind) => Array(t1, t2, t3, s"OBR_filaneme_$obrind").mkString("|")
```

On my current ennvironement I can't test the above so it may be subject to off by one errors or minor typos but the idea is there. But let me reiterate, this is not a job for spark.

EDIT: Just occured to me since there's only one part you could use a mapPartitions and just write the code how you would in Java/Scala within that partition.

The issue you were encountering is that the find is incorrect, it needs a different condition to work. Here is the simpler method I hinted to earlier with mapPartitions

```
val text: RDD[String] = sc.textFile(<path>)
val result: RDD[String] = text.mapPartitions{part =>
    var obrInd = 0
    part.map{r =>
        val code= r.split('|')(0)
        if(code == "OBR") obrInd += 1
        r + "|OBR_filename_" + obrInd
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me why `reduceByKey(Math.min)` is used ?

Comment: In spark operations which do not use the whole partition no row has any concept of any other row. eg) map cannot alter its output based on the contents of other rows. We need to combine the rows in some way to solve your problem. What I do is is combine all the rows together based on the OBR ID. I then take the minimum index (here index is row number) to get the first time that occurs. eg) in your sample you would get: 1 -> 0, 2 -> 4, 3 -> 7. Then we use that later to decide which index should go to which OBR ID. Occurs to me now it may not be needed if OBR rows each have a unique id

Comment: I tried your way but i am getting this result 



`OBR|1|METABOLIC PANEL|OBR_filaneme_1
OBX|1|Glucose|OBR_filaneme_2
OBX|2|BUN|OBR_filaneme_2
OBX|3|CREATININE|OBR_filaneme_2
OBR|2|RFLX TO VERIFICATION|OBR_filaneme_2
OBX|1|EGFR|OBR_filaneme_3
OBX|2|SODIUM|OBR_filaneme_3
OBR|3|AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT|OBR_filaneme_3
OBX|1|POTASSIUM|OBR_filaneme_3`

Comment: your edited answer i tried i am getting `OBR|1|METABOLIC PANEL|OBR_filename_1
OBX|1|Glucose|OBR_filename_1
OBX|2|BUN|OBR_filename_1
OBX|3|CREATININE|OBR_filename_1
OBR|2|RFLX TO VERIFICATION|OBR_filename_2
OBX|1|EGFR|OBR_filename_0
OBX|2|SODIUM|OBR_filename_0
OBR|3|AMBIGUOUS DEFAULT|OBR_filename_1
OBX|1|POTASSIUM|OBR_filename_1
`

Comment: The only way for the incrementer to decrease in the second example is f the file is read into multiple partitions. Use only one core. ie.) Stop using spark.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I cant tell you how much greatfull i am to you. I am upvoting and accepting it. Thanks a lot for your help. If you liked the question please upvote. I'll surely consider not using spark suggestion.

Comment: I used `coalesce(1)` and it solved my problem. But is it good to use `coalesce(1)` ?

Comment: coalesce(1) brings all data into a single partition. There's nothing wrong with that if the file is sufficiently small. I'd reckon you're better off doing a collect possibly however which brings it into a single array on the driver. It is theoretically possible however that the parts get put together in the wrong order however I doubt this will happen. So I reckon you're ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am so grateful to you.